# Best ways to use free electricity?

Tags: home, electricity

We've intentionally oversized our solar panel array to have capacity for an EV we're planning to buy once our current cars punch out. Until then we produce and push back to the grid an excess. This excess is carried as a credit for 12 months towards our future power usage. I am wondering what would be a possible household way of converting this excess into dollars and cents. One example I can think of is coin mining, but it marginally effective these days due to dominance of specialized mining hardware/farms. Any creative ideas are welcome!

Comment: Are we to assume that this essentially just needs to be a temporary way to use your excess power? Presumably, when you get your EV, you will no longer have an excess? In which case, you really need to calculate approximately how many KWh in total you need to "waste" in order to determine how much capital expenditure is viable to outlay.

Comment: This question is off topic, I'm afraid; lifehacks is about "problems seeking solutuons", not "solutions in search of a problem". In general questions of the form "tell me N ways to use X" style lists, where all answers are equally valid and so varied that there can be little logical consensus on what is the "right" answer for the problem in the question, are ill suited to the SE network

Comment: Work with neighbors?

Comment: I am not up-voting the question because you actually want a business idea for free. But some of the answers are actually good, and even within the rules of the site.

Answer (score 5):

If you have any gas appliances (range/oven, dryer, water heater), replace them with electric ones.

Answer (score 5):

Do not know where you are from, but in France, some are able to sell their excess electricity to the state and have the option of purchasing extra electricity from the state at a very reduced price in times when their system is down for whatever reason.

You may also wish to store some of your electricity in batteries designed for such storage.

- [BU-413a: How to Store Renewable Energy in a Battery](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/bu_413a_storing_renewable_energy_in_a_battery)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where you live, there might be e-bike or e-scooter rental services around. These companies put a number of devices out on the streets in big cities, but collecting all of them to recharge the batteries is too much effort. So they contract people and pay them to recharge their devices, usually paying the current end customer power prices.

This solution is tied to some effort, because you have to go out, collect the e-bikes or e-scooters in the streets around you and put them back in the streets after recharging the batteries.

Comment: ProTip™: If you do this, please do _NOT_ leave them in the middle of the sidewalk when you're done! That really seemed to be the thing to do last summer where I live. It's really _quite_ annoying to those use the sidewalks for... walking...

Answer (score 3):

You can also host your own server using the free electricity available and make money from the server. For instance, see this [webpage](https://hostimul.com/make-money-with-a-dedicated-server/), and here is a detailed post on [return on investment](https://www.lifewire.com/how-much-money-can-you-make-as-hosting-reseller-3473705) from housing a server.

From https://hostimul.com/make-money-with-a-dedicated-server/

> All sites need a hosting server to host their website data such as the articles, media files on their website such as the visual data (video files and images), and user data (which should be hosted and protected on a high safety level). That is the point where you can consider providing a personal income within the virtual platform with the method of making money with a server. What we are going to explain in this article is the main concept and its principles to start a legitimate revenue on a virtual basis with the technical resources. A Host is a server that is the connection between your website and your clients to maintain a constant data connection. All sites have a server which can be different when it comes to methods or plans that you are going to utilize which can also change in line with your individual and corporate needs such as the difference between hosting your personal blog data as several media files and articles and hosting an e-commerce website with an enormous number of products. Most independent company sites utilize a common server (which is referred to shared servers in which you share the technical properties of the same server with other users in order to pay slightly less in comparison with the dedicated servers, which is not the right and effective way of how to make money with servers). This implies they pay a little expense every month to impart a server to different organizations. However, there are other types of enterprises that possess a high volume of traffic on their website with the only solution to make a dedicated server as their main hosting provider.

Answer (score 3):

You said you were planning on getting an EV. Why not install a charger for the car now and then advertise it as a place people can charge theirs until you get your car?